# Vector spaces and fields

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology

When the definition of a vector space starts of, it says: A vector space $V$ over a field $F$.

I want to know what it means when it is said that: "over a field $F$".

I know what a field is but I just want to know what is meant by "over a field $F$"?

Comment: I believe it simply means the scalars associated with the vector space are from the field $F.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a common but somewhat abbreviated phrasing that can be slightly confusing at first. What it means is just something like

> If $F$ is a field, then a "vector space over $F$" means a set $V$ together with operations ${+}:V\times V\to V$ and ${\cdot}:F\times V\to V$, such that ...

Thus, the term that is being defined is not "vector space over a field", but one definition that at once defines the meaning of "vector space over $\mathbb R$", "vector space over $\mathbb C$", "vector space over $\mathbb Q$" and so forth.

When we just say "vector space", it is left implicit which field it is a vector space over, often $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I was actually referring to the word "over" in "vector space over a field F".

Comment: @rert588: The word "over" does not have any particular meaning here, or at least none that I can see. It just happens to be the conventional choice of preposition to put between a vector space and its scalar field.

Answer (score 1):

A vector field has scalar multiplication, "over a field $F$" means that the scalars originate from $F$, you can for example have scalars come from $\Bbb F_9$ and so on. It doesn't need to be real or complex but just a generic field.